# How to Use Eigen with Pybind11

Tags: c++, eigen3, pybind11

### Issue description

I have a simple function as such

```
void test2(Eigen::Matrix4f& mat){
    std::cout << mat << std::endl;
}
```

In my Python code, I do this

```
pylc.test2(np.ones((4,4), dtype=np.float32))
```

But it crashes with

```
TypeError: test2(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4>) -> None

Invoked with: array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

What did I do wrong

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted?? I cant find this answer anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include <pybind11/eigen.h>`

i forgot to put this..